# Time arithmetics in SQL TABLE DEFAULT

Tags: sql, firebird

In my table I want to set default of a column to 30 days from now. This needs to be a real, not computed column. Something like

> alter table T_NAME alter column EXPIRATION set default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 2592000

is not valid, but you get the idea. I am sure I can do that with a before insert trigger, but I was just wondering if there is a trick for doing arithmetics in default clause that I just don't know about.

My DB is Firebird 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is, as the Language Reference gives both for [CREATE TABLE](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-create) and for [ALTER TABLE](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-alter):

> `[DEFAULT {<literal> | NULL | <context_var>}]`

I guess the trigger is indeed your only option.

Comment: Yes, triggers are needed for this. btw, to add 30 days, the correct is current_timestamp+30